# NameError: name 'fh' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to read in `nc` file and get the variables but I  get the error:

> NameError: name 'fh' is not defined

Here is my code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset 
import numpy as np  
my_example_nc_file = r'''\D:\UoR\Practice data\cru10min30_tmp.nc'
fh = (my_example_nc_file, mode='r')'''
lons = fh.variables['lon'][:]
lats = fh.variables['lat'][:]
tmax = fh.variables['Tmax'][:]
tmax_units = fh.variables['Tmax'].units
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read .nc (netcdf) files using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360469/read-nc-netcdf-files-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset 
import numpy as np  
my_example_nc_file = r'''\D:\UoR\Practice data\cru10min30_tmp.nc'''
fh = Dataset(my_example_nc_file, mode='r')
lons = fh.variables['lon'][:]
lats = fh.variables['lat'][:]
tmax = fh.variables['Tmax'][:]
tmax_units = fh.variables['Tmax'].units
```

try this.

you converted the line where fh was defined by closing it in strings

Comment: Hi Sharma, Thanks for your answer but when Itry this it complains showing this  fh = (my_example_nc_file, mode ='r')
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I think you're missing out on the syntax, which library are you using to create fh? I would double check for the initialization of fh

Comment: I cant figure out how to do this, could you please help me here

Comment: but it brings back this error                                                                       
       tmax_units = fh.variables['Tmax'].units
                                          ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal